# Can I use single input form to collect data from multiple Activities in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

So hello everyone! Greetings for the day!

There are serveral Activities in Android studio I have to get data with. Total of 6 data inputs. However one user enters data for only one of them.

Here's the design sketch.
https://ibb.co/X5yyzQM

So do I have to design 6 Activities with input forms like this or is there any method to use one input form to use for 6 activities and get data with unique form value to the database?

Like BanquetStarter(name, address..) , BanquetBronze(name, address..) etc.

Appreciate your kind help. Appologies for your valuable time.
Thanks ❤.

Comment: Off the cuff, that seems like that should be one activity and four fragments (basically one fragment for each row of screens in your diagram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are separate screens, but do not necessarily have to be separate activities. Consider architecting this with `Fragment`s. This would allow you to utilize a single `ViewModel` bound to the lifecycle of the `Activity`. Each fragment would be responsible for collecting its own information and handing that into the `ViewModel`, and then once all the information is submitted, you have it all in one place and ready to go.

Activities are heavy weight components, whereas Fragments are lighter weight. Unless you have a very good, explicit reason to do so, prefer a single activity approach with multiple fragments (or multiple composable screens, if this app is being written from scratch utilizing Jetpack Compose).

Comment: This would be a lot easier - the problem with Activities is they're like standalone components, moving from one to the other is like starting a whole other, separate thing. So to share your data you'd have to store what you have so far, and reload it when the other Activity opens. That or pass the data directly from one to the next through the (very limited) Bundle system. Fragments and ViewModels make it all a lot easier - your data is just *there*, in the VM, and swapping to another Fragment doesn't change that. The whole Fragment and VM system was developed to make things easier